# How to count total comment in a category not a topic

Tags: php, mysql, database

My database:

```
category (cat_id,cat_name)
topic (topic_id,cat_is)
comment(com_id,topic_is)
```

Now I want to count total comment in a category.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: You need to have an idea. Without it you can't do anything.

Comment: Read SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cat_id, count(1) cnt 
     from category 
     join topic on cat_is = cat_id
     join comment on topic_is = topic_id
  group by cat_id
```